# Examine the uniform convergence of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}}$ if $x \in [0, \infty]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Examine the uniform convergence of the series
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}}$$
>   if $x \in  [0, \infty)$

Which series should I choose in Weierstrass M-test to show that is divergent?

Of course  $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ and this series diverges (and for $x = 0$ function series is divergent), yet $$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}} \geqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}}$$ for positive x, so it do not work.

Comment: The series is nowhere convergent.

Comment: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}}\geqslant\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int_{x+n}^{x+n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\int_{x+1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt=+\infty$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n > x$ you can approximate $\sqrt{x + n} \le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}$